# viewDidUnload ,viewWillDisappear not called in tabBarContoller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am making a view based application in which the first controller is viewcontroller there is login screen ,after login the next view is tabbar controller and  I have 2 tabbar items  on that tabbar .
Until this everything works fine . Now when i switch between these two views the `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidUnload` is not called of previous tab clicked .

P.S.Even the viewwillAppear was not called ,which i called it with the Default Notification. Don't know what the issues are. Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: What are you calling to make the UITabBarController's view the front view?

Comment: did you forget (BOOL)animated?

Comment: There is a similar problem to this and here is my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33701499/1035899

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, when switching view in a UITabBarController, the `viewDidUnload` function is not called because the view is not actually unloaded. So, this is normal.

What should work out of the box is `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidDisappear`. But there is a catch.
Depending on how you show your views, it might be that `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidDisappear` are not called by the framework for you. For example, this happens if you add your view as a subview, but there are more cases. I don't know how you display your tab bar, so cannot say anything more specific about it.

The easy solution I suggest to fix this is overriding the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` selector in you tab bar controller delegate. From there you could implement you own logic or call `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: @ sergio thanks for your inputs. Should i call viewDidDisappear with  Default Notification (same as i called the vieWillAppear method) .Isnt that wrong way i suppose.If its correct way then i can do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your TabBar controller in MainWindow.xib.

First when you show loginscreen you will add your RootViewController like this:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.rootview.view];
```

And when login is complete you can remove your RootViewController from mainwindow and add TabBarController in the mainwindow like this:

```
    [self.rootview.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a UINavigationController? You don't refer to one. If you aren't using a UINavigationController then it is likely that your UITabBarController isn't getting set up properly as the topViewController.