# How to call viewWillDisappear method in Tabbar Application having navigations also

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have created 5 Tabs in my application. In **Tab1** i have `UITableView`. On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i am navigating to another UIView in which I am showing my all 5 Tabs. And I also play song in that navigated view.

Now when I click **Back** button in navigation and i again go to my original view, i am able to call `viewWillDisappear` (as expected and normal situation).

But when I click directly another tab then `viewWillDisappear` is not called in the navigated View. Why this Happens??

I have just thought in a way that when I directly clicks the another Tab then the view in **Tab1** will call **viewWillDisappear**. But the navigated view will not call that method.

So what could be possible solutions?? kindly give some hints...

Comment: have you added tab bar programatically ?

Comment: no it is taken at design time only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to catch the event when you switch between tabs. When you switch from **Tab1** to **Tab2**, as you expect, `viewWillDisappear` of **Tab1** will not be called. Instead, the `viewWillAppear` of **Tab2** will be called.

Else if you want to catch the event when you switch tabs, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041982/how-to-get-the-event-that-switch-tab-menu-on-iphone).

Answer (score 13):

I got the viewWillDisappear to work by calling

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

in viewDidLoad()

Otherwise, viewWillDisappear wasn't getting called. And this is what I have in it:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.searchController.active = false
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for using `definesPresentationContext`, definitely a better approach then event catching on the TabBarController

Answer (score 2):

That is because the you have created tabBarController and you are pushing it as a viewController from the mainView.

So whole TabBarController is treated as one viewController.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But then how can i call the navigated view in my Tabbar as a tabbar controller view...???

Comment: which application are you working on? which requires you this kindoff structure?

Comment: I have music application in which on Tab1 i have table and for selecting music i navigate to player with navigation and other tabs are for photos, favourites, etc...

Comment: @DShah: But why can you not keep table view in first tab and all the other functions on the other tabs of the same tabBarController?

Comment: sorry but i think you are not getting my question. My main problem is that i cannot get reference of my navigated view (which is not a part of tabbar) but navigated from Tab1 or any other tab. things remains same with any of the tab.

Comment: Ok then may be from next time it would be better if you put one or two screenshots of your app and explain it how exactly the problem arises. Anyways I think you have got your answer from Developer as you have marked his answer as accepted.

Comment: i will try to put screenshots from next time if possible.. and yes i able able to solve the problem somehow.. thanx for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call this method create the nsnotification center object viewWillDisappear
and when you want to call this method post this notification.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I got it to work.

```
// UITabBarControllerDelegate
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        print("Selected view controller")

        // do stuff...
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

        return true
    }
```